# How do I "inverse" a diff file?

Tags: diff, patch

Say I have a diff file looking basically like the following.

```
+line a
-line b
```

Is it possible to do one (or both) of the following:

- Inverse this file (so I'd get)

  ```
  -line a
  +line b
  ```
- Pass some argument to `patch` so the end result the same as applying
  the inversed diff file described above

Comment: You can change the order you put in the files. eg. diff a.txt b.txt -> diff b.txt a.txt.

Comment: Are you looking for `patch --reverse`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell Does `--reverse` take a patch file?

Comment: @OneTwoThree why don't you try? =)

Answer (score 9):

To rewrite a reversed / inverted diff file, use `interdiff` from [diffutils](http://cyberelk.net/tim/software/patchutils/):

```
interdiff -q my-diff-file /dev/null
```

Answer (score 9):

You can leave the diff as is and apply in reverse

```
git apply --reverse backwards-diff
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is what you should do (assuming *newFile.txt* is the file you want to apply the reversed diff file on and *diffFile.txt* is the diff file):

```
patch -R newFile.txt diffFile.txt -o oldFile.txt
```